# How to change total amount of lumens?

Tags: private-network

I'm playing with Stellar private network on my local and wondering if is it possible to change the total supply of lumens in the network. It's well known that Stellar has 100bil coins but how to change this number isn't clear for me. I found `totalCoins` variable in Stellar-ledger.x but it has a comment saying it's responsible for a number of stroops in 1 XLM (10mil by default).

So, is it even possible to do that, or I just need to burn 80bil using horizon api...?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs this, total supply is hardcoded here - https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/b2f4ad5007a680cd666f9308b3eb0a3bb09177c5/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L79

```
namespace stellar
{

const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_SEQ = 1;
const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_VERSION = 0;
const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_BASE_FEE = 100;
const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_BASE_RESERVE = 100000000;
const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_MAX_TX_SIZE = 100;
const int64_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_TOTAL_COINS = 1000000000000000000; <---here
```

that's the total amount of stroops. and if you divide it by 10mil you'll get a total amount of XLM.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to send the XLM you want to destroy to an account with no signers (including a master key weight of 0).